# php to echo firstname if authenticated

Tags: php, mysql

I have written a PHP script that I use for authentication with e-mail and password since e-mail is identified as unique.

I want to echo "true" as well as echo :: fname (First Name). how can I write it? Following is my PHP code.

```
include "db_config.php";

$email = $_POST['email'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

$sql = "select fname,e_mail,password from user where e_mail = '$email' and pwd = '$password'  ";

$result = mysql_query($sql);

if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0){
    echo "true";
}
else{
    echo "Login Failed";
}
```

If you can suggest me some better way to write this code, please let me know.

Comment: You should use `mysqli_` function instead of `mysql_`.

Comment: If you use the old `mysql_*` functions, then you should always escape your input with `mysql_real_escape_string()`! But I would advice you to use PDO or the MySQLi extension.

Comment: Password field: `bob' OR 1=1;--`

Comment: thnx guys :), any idea how i can echo the fname?

Comment: What @LawrenceCherone wanted to say: You should read up on [SQL injections](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_injection) as they can be used to bypass the whole authentication.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the comments about mysql_* and mysql_real_escape_string, but after you get your result, you echo it like this, [adapted from the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php):

```
$result = mysql_query($sql);
if (!$result) {
    echo "Could not successfully run query ($sql) from DB: " . mysql_error();
    exit;
}

if (mysql_num_rows($result) == 0) {
    echo "No rows found, nothing to print so am exiting";
    exit;
}

$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result); 
echo "true" . $row['fname'];
```

Comment: ;) its kool :).... by any means do u know... now in my android, i get the echo as if (str.toString().equalsIgnoreCase("true")) {} n do something. as well how to get the fname to string?

Comment: Don't know anything about androids, but just use PHP to assign it to a string: $mystring = $row['fname'], then do whatever you want with it.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0)
{
    echo mysql_result($result, 0);
}
```

-- or --

The code from [Sankalp's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11485762/1494505) or [GDP's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11485710/1494505) answers. (mysql_fetch_array)
[`mysql_result`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-result.php) is not good if you want to display many results, it's good for just a few of them.

---

BTW, I'd like to point you to some omissions in your code:

- you should check if every `$_POST` or `$_GET` variables are set by using [`isset`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) or [`empty`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php).
- your code is so insecure! You should escape every variable before using it in a query. Use [`mysql_real_escape_string()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) for that. I also suggest you to use [`strip_tags()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php) along with escaping.

**Example of checking if variables are set**:

*Using [`isset()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php)*:

```
if(isset($_POST['email'])) $email = $_POST['email'];
if(isset($_POST['password'])) $password = $_POST['password'];
```

*Using [`empty()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php)*:

```
if(!empty($_POST['email'])) $email = $_POST['email'];
if(!empty($_POST['password'])) $password = $_POST['password'];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_NUM)
echo $row[0];   //fname
echo $row[1];   //email
```

or you can use MYSQL_ASSOC to get a named array and access values as

```
echo $row['fname'];
```